# Level plot / contour plot for x y z data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reproduce the following graph.
Z is a function of X and Y.
The graph shows 3 datapoints (white dots), as well as contour lines showing all possible values for z for any combination of x and y.

[image: Example of the graph I am trying to produce]

Here's what I have so far:

```
funct <- function(x,y) sqrt((1-x)^2+(1-y)^2)
df <- data.frame(x = c(0.3, 0.6, 0.8), 
                 y = c(0.7, 0.4, 0.9), 
                 z = funct(x,y))

grid <- expand.grid(x = seq(0,1,0.01), y = seq(0,1,0.01))

ggplot(grid, aes(x, y, z = funct(x,y))) +  
  geom_contour()
```

So I've managed to draw a grid with the contour lines, but am still missing:

- How to add the 3 data points to that grid
- How to color the contour lines and add a legend

Would be greatful for someone pointing me into the right direction!

Thanks, Lena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```r
ggplot(grid, aes(x, y, z = funct(x,y))) +  
  geom_contour_filled(color = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#000000", "#5F0000", "#BF0000", "#FF1F00", 
                               "#FF7F00", "#FFDF00", "#FFFF3F", "#FFFF9F")) +
  geom_point(data = df, shape = 21, size = 3, fill = "white",
             color = "dodgerblue")
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing Adam, thank you so much! I hadn't come across the "geom_contour_filled" function yet, despite quite some searching.